# Fill the area between two curves in gnuplot

Tags: plot, latex, gnuplot

I two functions:

```
f(x) = x**2
g(x) = -(x-4)*x
```

I need to calculate the area between these two curves, for that I would like to have visualization. WolframAlpha has exactly what I want: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=area+between+the+curves+y%3Dx%5E2+and+y%3D-x%5E2%2B4x, however, I need to make the graphics in gnuplot. Here is my code so far:

```
set border linewidth 1
set style line 1 linecolor rgb '#0060ad' linetype 1 linewidth 1
set style line 2 linecolor rgb '#dd181f' linetype 1 linewidth 1
set key at 6.1,1.3
set xlabel 'x'
set ylabel 'y'
set xrange [-0.5:3]
set yrange [0:5]
set xtics 2
set ytics 2
set tics scale 2
f(x) = x**2
g(x) = -(x-4)*x
set grid ytics lt 0 lw 1 lc rgb "#bbbbbb"
set grid xtics lt 0 lw 1 lc rgb "#bbbbbb"
plot f(x) title 'f(x)' with lines linestyle 1, \
     g(x) title 'g(x)' with lines linestyle 2
```

It produces this output:

[image]

Is there any way I can highlight the area between these two curves like in WolframAlpha? Assuming that we know where they intersect (0 and 2), unless gnuplot can do that on its own.

If this is not something vanilla gnuplot is capable of I apologize, in that case some pointers to resources that can do that would be appreciated.

Comment: have you checked the gnuplot manual and `help filledcurves`? and this: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.4/fillcrvs.html

Comment: @theozh I have, unfortunately, since I am very new to gnuplot, I wasn't able to make a lot of sense of it. Still, I think that you can only fill the area under one curve, while I want to fill the area between two curves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved using `filledcurves` (see docs: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node245.html). You just need to use the `below` option to ensure *only* the area *between* the two curves is filled.

As an example, try this:

```
plot '+' using 1:(f($1)):(g($1)) title '' with filledcurves below lc rgb 'green', \
    f(x) title 'f(x)' with lines linestyle 1, \
    g(x) title 'g(x)' with lines linestyle 2
```

This is based on the way its described in the FAQ here for two curves: http://www.gnuplot.info/faq/#x1-460005.3

Comment: Thank you, this somewhat works. The area between the two is now filled with green. However, the `'+' using 1:(f($1)):(g($1))` appears as a string on the top right. Here is the current plot: https://i.imgur.com/3kzxslX.png Is this intended behavior, or did I do something wrong, and if it is, how can I turn that label off?

Comment: Try adding `title ''`, updated the example.